# How can I defend against Pokémon Cinccino “Fluffy Tail”

Tags: pokemon

I’m trying to learn how to play the Pokémon tcg and can’t find an answer that makes sense online. My opponent used Cinccino’s Fluffy Tail attack, which does 30 damage, and also puts the defending Pokémon asleep.

Without a slew of cards that can wake up my defending Pokémon, I don’t understand how to defend against this kind of attack. They can just keep wicking 30 hp off my Pokémon, and I can’t attack back, turn after turn. It’s both frustrating and boring, as far as I understand the rules.

Is there any defense against this that doesn’t require me to have a very particular helper card handy?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be flipping a coin between every turn whenever a Pokémon of yours is asleep.

On Heads, it wakes up, so you have a 50%  chance of being able to use your Pokémon, and only on a Tails would you need any special items.

> ## Asleep
>
> Turn the Pokémon counterclockwise to show that it is Asleep.
>
> If a Pokémon is Asleep, it cannot attack or retreat. **Between turns, flip a coin. If you flip heads, the Pokémon wakes up** (turn the card right-side up), but if you flip tails, it stays Asleep.

*emphasis added*

---

In a comment, it is noted that excess difficulty may arise from flipping a coin between "rounds" instead of between turns (i.e. after every second turn, not every turn). As Pokémon TCG has no concept of rounds, only turns, this should make it much easier to have an active Pokémon that is awake at the start of the turn, without using Trainer Cards or other effects.

Comment: I thought I was supposed to flip a coin after every round, not each player’s individual turn. That does make a big difference.

Comment: There is no concept of "rounds" in Pokémon, only turns.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the point about flipping coins, you also can switch your Pokémon with a Pokémon on the bench using Switch or Escape Rope or Guzma, or evolve your Pokémon if possible. You also could put on an Escape Board, which would allow you to retreat while asleep.  Any of those options would remove the Sleep condition (once it goes to the bench, the condition is removed).